# An Alternative to JqueryUI?

Tags: jquery-ui, size

I'm using jquery ui in my page for a dropdown menu. But this file has a large size (198KB) and increased my page load time.
Is there any alternative for this file? or is it possible to edit this file and remove some useless codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you go to this page at jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/download

you can pick what all you need to download.  Also, make sure you get the minimized version.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to do the same for mootools?

Comment: I know little to nothing about MooTools, but it looks like there is a similar ui using mootools here: http://ui.moolego.org/ and you can get a minimized version of mootools here: http://mootools.net/download